# Do we need to maintain Authentication and Authorization Logic separately?

Tags: authentication, authorization, permissions, sso

We are using Keycloak Identity server which will take care of Authentication and Authorization for our new Multi Level Marketing Website.

There was a discussion going on within our team to maintain Authorization concepts separately in our local database. As we need to use ID server only for Authentication it seems.

**What are the best practices to maintain Authorization and Authentication logic separately?**

Comment: What do you mean by `Authorization concepts` in this scenario?

Comment: @Jedi maintaining roles and permissions of the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need to maintain Authentication and Authorization Logic separately?

Yes, yes, yes!

These are two different tasks.  Conflating the two incorrectly is one of the most common sources of vulnerability.

Number 2 and 4 of the OWASP top 10 this year, specifically:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2017-Top_10

Authentication is "who are you" and authorization is "what can you do."

Authenticating a user does *not* authorize them, and being authorized is no guarantee of authentication.